# Can PHP syntax highlight be updated?

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

See [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/91283/16495). PHP syntax highlight is clueless about namespaces:

[image]

First letter of a class name in a root namespace should not be black. Could this be updated? I know namespaces aren't most popular feature of PHP, but they are quite important one.

Comment: afaik it can't be *updated*. So doesn't provide the engine for syntax its just taken from google. You can submit your request to google though see the link

Comment: Wasn't in the queue yet, at least not as far as I could find. https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=313